# Equivalence of PROBIT function of SAS in Python

Tags: python, sas, statistics

I want to use the probit function of SAS but now in Python. 
For example in SAS, if I do :

probit(.025) the result is : -1.959963985

So I would like to have the same thing in this other language...

Thank you !

NB: SAS doc : http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245933.htm

Note that the PROBIT function in SAS returns the quantile from the standard normal distribution, given a probability as input (from docs):

> The PROBIT function returns the pth quantile from the standard normal distribution. The probability that an observation from the standard normal distribution is less than or equal to the returned quantile is p

Comment: Your answer is probably in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3438/calculating-percentile-of-normal-distribution

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site!  You'll get a better response if you ask your question as what you're trying to do in Python, rather than asking how a SAS function translates to Python.  You should explain what PROBIT does clearly, in addition to mentioning the similar function in SAS (which is helpful background information, it just shouldn't be the primary element of your question).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try following for Python 3.x:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
norm.ppf(0.025)
```